# jQuery override $.post success callback per form after initial general bind?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way in jQuery of setting all forms to a certain post request and then overriding specifically the success callback for each form?

Something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.post(url,function (){ callback actions});
});

$("form#foo").submit(function(){ 
    do the same 
    $.post(url, function(){ different actions});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the callbacks in an array, using the id of the form as  key. In your success callback you can do:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var f = this;
    $.post(url,
           function() { 
               callbacks[$(f).attr('id')]() ;
           }
    );
});
```

Comment: i assume you mean:
$("form").submit(function(e,callbacks[]){});
but how do i pass  them to the event? i thought of using .click in conjunction with trigger on the submit but it feels wrong...

Comment: $("form#foo").submit(function(){ 
    var that = this;
    $.post(url, function() { 
    callbacks[$(that).attr('id')](); 
});
});

Comment: i updated the answer! yes you could create a global callback array